Не создается таблица в mysql
Код:
$id = 1;
$text = "555";

$hostnamesite = "localhost"; 
$usernamesite = "namedef"; 
$passwordsite = "1234"; 
$dbNamesite = "namedef";
$link = mysqli_connect($hostnamesite,$usernamesite,$passwordsite,$dbNamesite);
mysqli_set_charset($link, "utf8mb4");
mysqli_query($link, "INSERT INTO table_eee('id','text') VALUES ('$id','$text')");

Не создается таблица в mysql. Как правильно?
